# Atmospheric friction

Tags: friction, atmospheric-science

So when you lift an object, atmosphere spills in from the sides to fill the empty space. That would mean that the atmosphere is pushing up against the side of the object. So wouldn't that mean that when you lift the object it is slightly slowed down because the atmosphere pushing up against the side of the object. If so, how would you calculate this? The friction would also generate heat, how would you calculate that too?

When an object is falling, atmosphere fills in above it, so when the atmosphere hit the object, wouldn't it both bounce off the object and propel it downward faster? Or would the atmosphere that the object is moving out of the way cancel out the speed gained from the atmosphere coming in from the top? Wouldn't the atmosphere hitting the top of the object also create friction? Would speed gained from the atmosphere hitting the top of the object also apply to atmosphere hitting the bottom of an object you pick up?

Comment: To understand this you would need a book, example https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236269076_Atmospheric_and_Oceanic_Fluid_Dynamics

Comment: It sounds as if you're describing [aerodynamic drag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)) i.e. the force due to the motion of the air (or it works for liquids as well) as the object moves through it.

Comment: [There is a more accessible article on it here](https://physics.info/drag/)

Comment: Also check induced mass. This is a purely inertial effect present even in superfluids. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Added_mass